# Coin with two heads

Tags: probability

I was at a job interview and got a question. You have a bag with 100 coins. One of these coins has two heads, other coins are regular. You get one coin from this bag, put it on a table and see head. What the probability that this coin has two heads? Thank you!

Comment: Check out [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> $2/101$
> You see one head among the $101$ possible heads, and $2$ of these heads belongs to the double-head coin so you have $2/101$ chances to have the double-head coin
>
>   The probability that you chose the double-head coin is twice the probability that you chose a specific normal coin

Maths explanation :

> Let's define :
>  * $X$ the event "You choose the special coin",
>  * $H$ the event "you see head"
>  * $T$ the event "you see tail"
>
>  We want to evaluate $P(X|H)$, the probability that we chose the special coin given that we see a head.
>  $P(X) = P(H)*P(X|H) + P(T)*P(X|T)$
>  $P(H) = \frac{101}{200}$ ,
>  $P(T) = \frac{99}{200}$
>  $P(X) = \frac{1}{100}$
>  $P(X|T) = 0$ (the coin can't be special if we see tail)
>  If we substitue :
>  $\frac{101}{200} P(X|H) = \frac{1}{100}$ so $P(X|H) = \frac{2}{101}$

Comment: Where do you get the values for $P(H)$ and $P(T)$?

Comment: You can also simplify this problem by considering the 100 coins to **be** 200 coin-faces.  So instead of drawing a coin + looking at one side, you perform a single operation: draw one coin-face.  Of all coin faces, 101 are heads and 2 of those are the double-heads.

Comment: @Trenin There As Florista explained, if you think about all the faces you can choose, there are 101 head and 99 tails and they are all equiprobable. $P(H)=\frac{101}{101+99}$ and $P(T)=\frac{99}{101+99}$

Comment: Currently Lord of dark has 666 rep.... I want to up-vote, but don't want you to lose that number.

Comment: I am the devil !